# How can I print the original title of the top 50 movies from themoviedatabase.org with python?

Tags: python, json, for-loop, themoviedb-api

hello all i'm learning python recently and i need to analyze the web of themoviedb.org website. I want to extract all the movies in the database and I want to print the original title of the first 50 movies.This is a piece of the json file that i receive as a response following my network request:

```
{"page":1,"results":[{"adult":false,"backdrop_path":"/5gPQKfFJnl8d1edbkOzKONo4mnr.jpg","genre_ids":[878,12,28],"id":76600,"original_language":"en","original_title":"Avatar: The Way of Water","overview":"Set more than a decade after the events of the first film, learn the story of the Sully family (Jake, Neytiri, and their kids), the trouble that follows them, the lengths they go to keep each other safe, the battles they fight to stay alive, and the tragedies they endure.","popularity":5332.225,"poster_path":"/t6HIqrRAclMCA60NsSmeqe9RmNV.jpg","release_date":"2022-12-14","title":"Avatar: The Way of Water","video":false,"vote_average":7.7,"vote_count":3497},{......}],"total_pages":36589,"total_results":731777}
```

And this is my code:

```
import requests

response = requests.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=my_key&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1&with_watch_monetization_types=flatrate")
jsonresponse=response.json()
page=jsonresponse["page"]
results=jsonresponse["results"]
for i in range(50):
  for result in jsonresponse["original_title"][i]:
        print(result)
```

My code don't work. Error: "KeyError: 'original_title'". How can I print the original title of the top 50 movies?

Comment: Try doing `print(results.keys())` to see what keys exist in the dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When formatting the json you posted properly:

```json
{
    "page": 1,
    "results": [
        {
            "adult": false,
            "backdrop_path": "/5gPQKfFJnl8d1edbkOzKONo4mnr.jpg",
            "genre_ids": [
                878,
                12,
                28
            ],
            "id": 76600,
            "original_language": "en",
            "original_title": "Avatar: The Way of Water",
            "overview": "Set more than a decade after the events of the first film, learn the story of the Sully family (Jake, Neytiri, and their kids), the trouble that follows them, the lengths they go to keep each other safe, the battles they fight to stay alive, and the tragedies they endure.",
            "popularity": 5332.225,
            "poster_path": "/t6HIqrRAclMCA60NsSmeqe9RmNV.jpg",
            "release_date": "2022-12-14",
            "title": "Avatar: The Way of Water",
            "video": false,
            "vote_average": 7.7,
            "vote_count": 3497
        },
        {
         ....
        }
    ],
    "total_pages": 36589,
    "total_results": 731777
}
```

one can easily see that `original_tile` is part of each dictionary / map in `results`. So using

```py
for result in results:
  print(result["original_title"])
```

should work.

Comment: hello thank you very much for the answer, I have a question: when I print the films, the program only prints a certain number of films and then they repeat. But if I want to print all 731777 how do I do it? i understand that the screen can't show all 731777 but how do i print up to 50 movies? because with the code written above, the title is printed but after a certain amount of terations, the films repeat themselves why?

Comment: @Elly I can only guess, but if you still have that `for i in range(50):` in your code, that means that you are printing out the first page of results 50x. What you need is the next page, properly by adjusting your query to the moviedb API.

Answer (score 0):

Were there any imports not listsed above? Which version of Python? 3.10?
There's not enough information to run this code. I believe Django has to be install to use jsonresponse. I have a similar need ergo the need for a functional copy.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35758922)

Comment: I was complaining that the code does not work, as is, and that there may be unmentioned sections missing from the page.